JWT Refresh Token Issue in Strapi: Credentials Fail After Logout and Re-login
I’m working on a Strapi project and have implemented a custom JWT refresh token function. The function issues a new JWT when a valid token is provided. Here’s my current implementation:
 plugin.controllers.auth.refreshToken = async (ctx) => {
    const params = _.assign(ctx.request.body);

    try {
      // const { id } = await strapi.plugins[
      //   "users-permissions"
      // ].services.jwt.verify(params.jwt);

      const payload = jwt.decode(params.jwt, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

      if (payload) {
        const RAW_SQL = `SELECT id FROM up_users WHERE id = ${payload.id}`;

        const entriesResult = await strapi.db.connection.raw(RAW_SQL);
        const rows = entriesResult.rows;

        if (_.size(rows) === 1) {
          const user = _.first(rows);

          ctx.send({
            jwt: strapi.plugins["users-permissions"].services.jwt.issue(
              {
                id: user.id,
              },
              { expiresIn: "7d" }
            ),
          });
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return ctx.badRequest(null, "Invalid token");
    }
  };

Issues Encountered:
Token Refresh: After refreshing the token, it updates automatically on the front-end, and I can continue consuming private endpoints without issues.
Login After Logout: The problem arises when I log out and then try to log in again. The credentials fail, and I'm unable to authenticate properly.
Questions:
Are there any issues with the way I’m handling JWT refresh tokens?
Could there be a problem with how tokens are managed or stored after logout and re-login?
What might be causing the credentials to fail upon re-login?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Additional Information:
Strapi version: 4.x
React Native (Front-End)
